# SOAP UI - Increase font size

Tags: soap

My font on Soap UI 5.2.1 is very small and I am using a Dell XPS laptop running Windows OS 8.1. I have tried changing the font from the editor settings in preferences and also changed the UI settings to use native look & feel yet still no results. I restarted the application several times checking if it took the changes but no luck.

Comment: same problem, native look and feel setting under UI Settings didn't help either

Answer (score 1):

I did as below, it works fine after restart SoapUI

1.Change text font: File > Preferences -> Editor Settings -> Select Font -> Size
[image]

2.Change UI font: Properties -> Compatibility -> Change high DPI settings -> Overide high ... -> System
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open your soap-ui select File > Preferences from menu and then pick Editor Settings group. Hit Select Font... next to Edtor Font and choose a different size/font face.

Hit OK to confirm your changes.Now restart your SOAP-UI.

You can also see details here [How to increase text size in SoapUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156005/how-to-increase-text-size-in-soapui)